# Are the SCL repos of PHP kept up to date?

Tags: php, centos, software-collections

I noticed that the SCL version of PHP is still at 7.1.8 while the latest PHP 7.1 version is 7.1.15.

This is the collection's site: https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/rh-php71/

And here are the packages: http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/sclo/x86_64/rh/rh-php71/

Are the SCL repos kept up to date or is 7.1.8 the latest version that will be released PHP 7.1 SCL?

Comment: It doesn't appear that they are. PHP 7.0 is still on 7.0.10, instead of 7.0.28, while PHP 7.2 isn't available at all. It appears that SCL doesn't really get much attention from RH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SCL packages are maintained and updated using the same policy that the base distribution.

See [Backporting Security Fixes](https://access.redhat.com/security/updates/backporting/)

But with a shorter life cycle, see [Red Hat Software Collections Product Life Cycle](https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/rhscl/)

Comment: Thanks! I was having trouble finding that info on the life cycle. If I'm understanding correctly: PHP 7.2.x may be released in SCL 4.0? Any insight what factors determine when a major release stream is decided upon?

Comment: 5.6, 7.0, 7.1 were available <1 year after upstream release. Can"t say for 7.2